# DataTable deleted wrong row by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in JavaScript. I got some bug but don't know what to call it.

I have a  data table and want to create a function that can delete current data table row.

I use an alert for testing and it's all good, but it deleted the first data table row.
[image]

My code

```
   $('#calEvents').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
   var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
 

  
   var confirmalert = confirm("Are you sure?");
   if (confirmalert == true) {
      document.getElementById("calEvents").deleteRow(data);
      alert( data[0] +"'s EVENT is: "+ data[ 5 ] );

 
        
          }else{
        alert('Invalid ID.');
          }
```

I know in my code the delete/edit button works the same, but its just for testing. If u got some tips or tricks please tell me.

EDIT. Add html code.

```
<table class="table display" id="calEvents">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">GROUP</th>
                <th scope="col">WEEKDAY</th>
                <th scope="col">DATE</th>
                <th scope="col">TICKER</th>
                <th scope="col">EVENT</th>
                <th scope="col">READX</th>
                <th scope="col">ACTION</th>
           
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">GROUP</th>
                <th scope="col">WEEKDAY</th>
                <th scope="col">DATE</th>
                <th scope="col">TICKER</th>
                <th scope="col">EVENT</th>
                <th scope="col">READX</th>
                <th scope="col">ACTION</th>
    
               
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: Not sure, but why not `table.deleteRow(data)` instead of 
`document.getElementById("calEvents").deleteRow(data);` ?

Comment: i try this one before, but its not working

Comment: can you add demo code ?

Comment: what kind of code u want?

Comment: @mausasu1234 with html and js so that  it would be more clear to find out where is the issue .

Comment: js code you can see. Html i dont think its important because its just basic table. But i add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first need get row. I found how to do it like this:

```
  var row= this.parentNode.parentNode;
```

then just

```
  document.getElementById("calEvents").deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
```